# Can a user-defined deduction guide be constrained by a trailing requires-clause?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Is the following code example legal? What does the C++20 standard say about it?

```
template<typename...>
struct s { s(auto) {} };
s(auto) -> s<> requires true;
static_assert(sizeof(s{true})); // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc ok/crash
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Trovrsr19)

---

The error message from Clang:

```
<source>:7:25: error: deduction guide cannot have a requires clause
    7 | s(auto) -> s<> requires true;
      |
```

Comment: Open issue [CWG 2707](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2707) suggests adding a trailing requires-clause for deduction guides (but in a different position than your attempt).

Comment: Also, `auto` isn't allowed in a deduction guide either, see https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#3.sentence-1 and [CWG 2697](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2697).

Answer (score 5):

> Can a user-defined deduction guide be constrained by a trailing requires-clause?

Currently, no. A deduction guide does not declare a *template-head* by its own, in only refers to a *template-name*. From [[temp.deduct.guide]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#nt:deduction-guide), noting that a `simple-template-id` is also just referring to a template specialization:

> Deduction guides are used when a template-name appears as a type specifier for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]). Deduction guides are not found by name lookup. Instead, when performing class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct]), all reachable deduction guides declared for the class template are considered.
>
> ```
> deduction-guide:
>     explicit-specifier_opt template-name ( parameter-declaration-clause ) -> simple-template-id ;
> ```

The named template, on the other hand, may be constrained, as covered by [[temp.names]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#8)

> When the template-name of a simple-template-id names a constrained non-function template or a constrained template template-parameter, and all template-arguments in the simple-template-id are non-dependent ([temp.dep.temp]), the associated constraints ([temp.constr.decl]) of the constrained template shall be satisfied ([temp.constr.constr]).

Clang is thus correct to reject your example.

---

As pointed out by @user17732522, there is an open CWG issue, [CWG 2707](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2707), which proposes changing the grammar for deduction-guides to allow them to have trailing requires-clauses. This issue has not seen any activity since its inception, although it was planned to be discussed by CWG during this summers (June 2023) WG21 Varna meeting, but it seems like time didn't suffice to get to it.

> **2707. Deduction guides cannot have a trailing requires-clause**
>
> [...]
>
> The grammar for deduction-guide does not, but should, allow a trailing
> requires-clause:
>
> ```
> deduction-guide:
>    explicit-specifieropt template-name ( parameter-declaration-clause ) -> simple-template-id ;
> ```
>
> **Suggested resolution:**
>
> Change the grammar in 13.7.2.3 [temp.deduct.guide] paragraph 1 as
> follows:
>
> ```
> deduction-guide:
>    explicit-specifier_opt template-name ( parameter-declaration-clause ) requires-clause_opt -> simple-template-id ;
> ```